# Reset Modal Content when Closing

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

Had been trying to reset the validation of a Modal window using different javascript approaches. When attempted to use:

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
});
```

I receive an error:

```
SCRIPT28: Out of stack space
jquery-1.12.3.min.js (4,24467)
```

Tried this too but did not work either:

```
$('#formId').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $('#formId').formValidation('resetForm', true);
});
})
```

Basically I am using jquery.validate.js and jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js to validate the input fields before the form which resides in a modal window is submitted. I do not want to keep the error being displayed if the modal is closes and opened again. None of what I had tried worked.

Tried:
[Reset Bootstrap Modal if not all form steps are complete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12959331/reset-bootstrap-modal-if-not-all-form-steps-are-complete?rq=1)
[how to reset form on modal hidden or close?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26327323/how-to-reset-form-on-modal-hidden-or-close)
http://formvalidation.io/examples/modal/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just clear our all input types in your modal then: **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/84yTH/54/)**

```
$('.modal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).find('input').val('');
});
```

Also it would help to add this in your onReady:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    cache: false
})
```